# Attribute routing not working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I am using `Attribute Routing` in `MVC4` application. I have set route to `[Route("test-{testParam1}-{testParam2}")]`. Here `{testParam2}' may consist the word 'test'. For example, if I enter a url as below,

```
localhost:33333/test-temp-test-tempparam2
```

This gives me 404 error. Here in the url, here `{testParam2}` is having two words `test tempparam2` formatted to `test-tempparam2`. When `test` word is at last position of `{testParam2}`, it runs good. That means if the url is like `.../test-temp-tempParam2-test` runs good. But following give error. `.../test-temp-test-tempParam2`.

Below is the code that may help...

```
[Route ("test-{testParam1}-{testParam2}")]
public ActionResult Foo (int testParam2) {...}
```

Now try following two url.

1. `localhost:(port)/test-temp-1`
2. `localhost:(port)/test-test-temp-1`

In my case second gives error. In this case first parameter is formatted to `test-temp` from `test temp`. First runs good.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you use {testparam2} as test_tempparam2

Comment: Have a look at this project on GitHub. It is distributed as a nuget package. https://github.com/AtaS/lowercase-dashed-route

Comment: @DhavalR provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. That way it can be used to find better answers.

Comment: @NKosi please see edit.

Comment: Your controller method route is accepting two parameters delimited by a dash. So why are you passing 3 parameters in your URL? If your parameter has a dash, how do you expect the router to distinguish which is a delimiter and which is legitimately part of your parameter?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting in second case?

Comment: @DhavalR, I tested it and received 200 OK response for both URLs in OP. Unable to reproduce the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: @DhavalR when tested route data shows `testParam1=temp-temp2, testParam2=test` for the first URL and  `testParam1=temp-test, testParam2=temp2` for the second URL.

Comment: @FrankFajardo That's true. Actually I am not passing three parameters. The second param is formatted. eg. `tempParam2 = "test foobar"` than it's formatted to `test-foobar`.

Comment: @Nkosi Please see the edit. Can you try both url again. I apologize for taking more time. Actual problem is when we use last parameter as int in method. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @DhavalR, I don't need to test it again. If you had included that information up front I would have been able to tell you to use a route constraint. `[Route ("test-{testParam1}-{testParam2:int}")]`

Comment: @DhavalR what was the final outcome? Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

OP indicated that the last parameter in  the route template is an `int`

Use a route constraint.

Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. The general syntax is `{parameter:constraint}`. For example:

```
[Route ("test-{testParam1}-{testParam2:int}")]
public ActionResult Foo (int testParam2) {...}
```

Thus, when trying following two URLs.

```
localhost:(port)/test-temp-1

localhost:(port)/test-test-temp-1
```

The first would match route data `{testParam1 = temp}-{testParam2 = 1}`

And the second would match route data `{testParam1 = test-temp}-{testParam2 = 1}`

Comment: Well, I learnt about `constraint` in `Attribute Routing`. Your example and explanation is good. But I will go with `FrankFajardo's` comment. Because your code(url) works as you mentioned. But when it comes when `{tempParam1}` has more than two characters (e.g. temp-test-temp), it will throw error. If you have url like `test-temp-test-2`, then it will work. But when it's `test-temp-test-temp-2`, won't work. So had to change my `Attribute Route`  like `~/{tempParam1}-{tempParam2}` or `test/{tempParam1}-{tempParam2}`. BTW Thanks for your answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following piece of code in you Global.asax file?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```